# MySQL dial tcp 172.30.0.3:3306: connect: connection refused

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose

go web app get mysql dial connect err:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    build:
      context: ./docs/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    container_name: puzzle-mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    tty: true
    restart: always
    networks:
      - puzzle_network
  redis:
    image: redis:6.2.4
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    container_name: puzzle-redis
    restart: always
    networks:
      - puzzle_network
  server:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - "./:/workspace"
    container_name: puzzle-server
    environment:
      env: production
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    tty: true
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    networks:
      - puzzle_network

networks:
  puzzle_network:
    driver: bridge
```

docker-compose up -d then all containers is running:

[containers running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wZVa.png)

get server error log:

[2022-05-23 07:38:36.544]   production.info bootstrap/db.go:37  mysql connect info: {"info": "root:root@tcp(db:3306)/puzzle?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local"}

[2022-05-23 07:38:36.546]   production.error    bootstrap/db.go:52  Mysql connect failed, err:  {"err": "dial tcp 172.30.0.3:3306: connect: connection refused"}

[mysql contaienr info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lChhe.png)

help, how to solution?

Comment: change `root:root@tcp(db:3306)` to `root:root@tcp(127.0.0.1:3306)` in `bootstrap/db.go:37`

Answer (score -3):

solved!

Before running the server, you need to wait for the mysql service to be started.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).